# How to change color of icons and remove waves on buttton material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  buttonStyle: {
    color: "",
    background: "red",

    "&:hover": {
      transform: "scale(1.1)", // Scale by 10%
      background: "red",
    },
  },
});

   <div>
      <h1>Heloo</h1>
      <Button
        className={classes.buttonStyle}
        variant="contained"
        disableElevation
      >
        <ArrowBackIosIcon />
      </Button>
    </div>
```

> Defalt the button on click have waves, how to remove that, and how to
> style icons component to different color

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-h6gy3?file=/demo.js) of your code.

You can remove ripple (waves) effect by using the prop `disableRipple` [prop](https://material-ui.com/api/button/) on the button.

```
<Button
  className={classes.buttonStyle}
  variant="contained"
  disableElevation
  disableRipple
  disableFocusRipple>
    <ArrowBackIosIcon />
</Button>
```

There are multiple ways, using which you can update the styling of the icon. I've used the `type` selector to style the icon in the button. You can also use a className to style the icon. Below is a snippet from the `useStyles` in the attached sandbox link.

```
"& svg": {
  color: "white"
}
```